# Django Settings Module

Tags: python-3.6, django-1.11

I installed Django and was able to double check that the module was in fact in Python, but when attempting to implement basic commands such as runserver or utilize manage.py; I get DJANGO_SETTEINGS_MODULE error. I already used "set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = mysite.settings" as advised and inserted mysite.settings into the PATH for Python as some documentation online directed me to.

Now instead of undefined it says no such module exists. I can't find anything else in the documentation and I used my test site name instead of "mysite" without any change. Does anyone know what am I missing? All I can find in the module library for Django in my Python is this code.

---

from **future** import unicode_literals

```
from django.utils.version import get_version

VERSION = (1, 11, 5, 'final', 0)

__version__ = get_version(VERSION)


def setup(set_prefix=True):
    """
    Configure the settings (this happens as a side effect of accessing  the first setting), configure logging and populate the app registry.
Set the thread-local urlresolvers script prefix if `set_prefix` is True.
   """
    from django.apps import apps
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.urls import set_script_prefix
    from django.utils.encoding import force_text
    from django.utils.log import configure_logging

    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
    if set_prefix:
        set_script_prefix(
            '/' if settings.FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME is None else         force_text(settings.FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME)
    )
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you wrote properly the environment variable? I'm asking cause I see you get the error DJANGO_SETTEINGS_MODULE (settings has a misspelling)...